# husky bringup on an ARM platform

Tags: robotic-arm, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

i am currently trying to get my husky indigo setup working on an arm machine.
My problem is the `husky_node` of the `husky_base` package. Running it, i get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: TransportException 3: Unacknowledged send
[ERROR] [1438708451.166274559]: Error configuring velocity and accel limits: Unacknowledged send
```

The port is set correctly and also the port permission are r+w.

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215206/husky-bringup-on-an-arm-platform/) by [Tirgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2060/tirgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2015-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was interpretation bug for arm that was [fixed](https://github.com/husky/husky_robot/commit/fe2027bd9ddd873dbcc47debf8e773c984c76241).  Try installing from source.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0